# How to print just the populated values in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array that can store 25 values. Now, if I store just 5 values, the remaining 20 values in the array are automatically filled in as 0. And when I print the array, all 25 of those value come up. Is there any way to get only the populated(in this case 5) values and exclude the automatically filled 0's?

Comment: Iterate over them and check.

Comment: Yes. Now post your code so we can give you a real answer.

Comment: Have the array be of an object type, and not a raw type, and then check if the element of the array is null or not.

Comment: Can the actual data contain '0'?

Comment: have you considered setting unused values as null?

Comment: @Oak you cannot have a `null` in a raw-type array like `int` or `byte`

Comment: Initially all will be 0, when you want to read do as, if(arr[i]!=0) sop(arr[i]); //Make sure data that you are going to store should not contain 0 as that is the digit which you are using for condition.

Comment: I used arrays like this for a long time until one day I started using a list for these types of situations. Then, I realized how much time and effort I wasted in the past and how ugly my code looked.

Comment: @John You're right, forgot about that detail =)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to print any 0's, then this is trivial:

```
for(int x = 0;x < arr.length;x++)
{
    if(arr[x] == 0) continue;
    System.out.print(arr[x] + " ");
}
```

You could also just keep track of how much of the array you have filled:

```
int elements = 5
for(int x = 0;x < elements && x < arr.length;x++)
    System.out.print(arr[x] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a note of all the values you are filling up and then print only that much, for example every time you put a value in the array increment a variable n which was initially 0, and now while printing, print from 0 to n-1